Partial Fractions of $\frac{1}{(x+1)^{m}(x+3)^{n}}$
In the partial fractions decompostion of  $$\frac{1}{(x+1)^{m}(x+3)^{n}}$$
Is there any general formula for the coefficient of $\frac{1}{x+3}$ term? Of course, I am able to get the coefficients manually for given $m,n$. I do see the deominators following some $2^{k}$ type pattern and I am completely clueless about the numerator. Context: I am working on another problem and this happened to be a sub-step in that process. I am curious if there are closed looking answers (even if they involve summations containing Binomials for example).

Let $y:=x+3$. Since
$$\frac1{(x+1)^m(x+3)^n}=\frac1{(y-2)^my^n},$$
you are looking for the coefficient of $y^{n-1}$ in
$$\frac1{(y-2)^m}=\frac1{(-2)^m}\frac1{(1-y/2)^m}=\frac1{(-2)^m}\sum_{k=m-1}^{+\infty}{k\choose m-1}(y/2)^{k-m+1}.$$
This coefficient is
$$\frac1{(-2)^m}{m+n-2\choose m-1}(1/2)^{n-1}=\frac{(-1)^m}{2^{m+n-1}}{m+n-2\choose m-1}.$$

Very elegant. Thanks!

Using your method, I tired finding the coefficients of $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$ and $\frac{1}{(x+1)^3}$ . I get the following. Are they right? Coefficient of $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$ comes to $\frac{(-1)^m}{2^{m+n-2}}\binom{m+n-3}{n-1}$ and coefficient of $\frac{1}{(x+1)^3}$ comes to be $\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2^{m+n-3}}\binom{m+n-4}{n-1}$. I used the substitution $y=x+1$ and expanded. But I think I am not getting the right expression.

I find the same two coefficients as yours.

Another way...
$$\frac1{(x+1)^m(x+3)^n}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{A_i}{(x+3)^i}+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{B_j}{(x+1)^j}$$
If we multiply the above equation by $(x+3)^n$, take derivative of the equation $n-1$ times and let $x=-3$, we get
$$(-m)(-m-1)...(-m-n+2)(-2)^{-m-n+1}=A_1(n-1)!$$
Hence, $$A_1=\frac{(-1)^m}{2^{m+n-1}}{m+n-2\choose n-1}$$
